# SQL Server backup. PowerShell vs Python

Tags: sql-server, backup, powershell, python

I'm about to refactor inherited scripts deployed on multiple servers that backup many other servers. They are a mixture of cmd, vbs and sql. I'm pondering what benefits would bring doing it with Python since I find it friendlier to script?
Mainly i'm thinking that with PS I can use something that could be considered native like Invoke-Sqlcmd or sqlps. 
Is it just a matter of taste or might I stumble upon something nasty and unforeseen by using python?

Comment: [Just use Ola's scripts and be done.](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html)

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with Python, but for your current requirement (i.e. backup).
I'd strongly recommend you to use PowerShell for two reasons:

1. MS in its SQLPS module (since SQL Server 2012), has a native cmdlet called

   `Backup-SQLDatabase`
2. You may run this cmdlet on one central server to do the backup against **multiple** sql instances at once because this `Backup-SQLDatabase` can accept multiple sql instances, like the following example

   ```
   Backup-SQLDatabase -Database master -Server "my_server1", "my_server2" ...
   ```

   This 2nd point may help you to centralize all those backup scripts to one administration server (dedicated for DBA use) instead of sparsely stored on each sql server instance.

Also with MS providing `Backup-SQLDatabase`, you can be assured that it will be supported for all future new features. (For example, using this cmdlet to support Azure SQL Database etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's more than a matter of taste; it's a matter of who owns the scripts; if there are corporate practices for what is acceptable they need to be followed. These days there are a lot of options for scripting, but limiting the technology breadth is important; if you finish your refactoring, then leave, will they have to hire a python expert to carry them on while everything else is in PowerShell?

That said, as long as peers agree, and the output is documented and maintainable, you could make a case for either.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server SMO is another option.  I've had very good success doing backups & restores with C# using it.  It looks like you can access this library from Python if you are using Windows.

This site has an example backup syntax.

http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Using_SMO_to_manage_a_MS_SQL_Database

Comment: I also use SMO with Powershell to backup databases from both a SQL Express instance and SSAS databases.  +1 for bringing that up Ryan.